# Simple data operations: R vs python

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table

I have been happily using R for doing data analysis. By data analysis I mean: given a relatively small table (<1 mio rows, <100 columns), answer 'complicated' questions about the data like 'for each instance, what was the last event that happened before a specific point in time varying with the instance' and so forth.

In recent times I was put into an environment where people are using python. As far as I know, the only package for doing these things is pandas. Tried though I have, I am still struggling (after a few weeks) with the most simple operations. Let us consider this scenario: I am looking at processes (identified by a column PROC_ID) that consist of different events sorted by a column 'SORT_NR'. For some weird reason I want to do the following: Given a fixed process id proc_id I want to add a certain number 'add' to all SORT_NR such that SORT_NR >= start for a fixed parameter start. Example:

```
PROC_ID | SORT_NR
      A |       1
      A |       2
      A |       3
      A |       4
      A |       5
      B |       1
      B |       2
```

and I am calling this function now with proc_id=A, start=3, add=2 meaning that the expected result would be

```
PROC_ID | SORT_NR
      A |       1
      A |       2
      A |       5 <<< 2 was added
      A |       6 <<< 2 was added
      A |       7 <<< 2 was added
      B |       1
      B |       2
```

googling gave me the answer that this can be done via

> df.loc[(df['PROC_ID'] == proc_id) & (df['SORT_NR'] >= start),
>   'SORT_NR'] = df.loc[(df['PROC_ID'] == proc_id) & (df['SORT_NR'] >=
>   start), 'SORT_NR'] + add

I am writing that explicitly without formating it in order to make it clear: This command is a mess. Looking at it you do not have a chance to grasp easily what this is about. Let us now look at the respective command in R's data.table package:

> df[PROC_ID == proc_id & SORT_NR >= start, SORT_NR := SORT_NR + add]

so we see

1. in pandas we have a lot of repetition (you always have to repeat df if you want to access its columns which is not only unnecessary, it is even harmful if you rename the table)
2. we have additional completely unnecessary special characters: ' and brackets. That just distracts the eye.
3. all in all we use 154 characters for the pandas command and 68 (roughly a third!) characters in data.table

I do not want to start a flame war 'R vs python' I just want to know:

**Am I using pandas in a wrong way? Is there a hidden knowledge that is somewhat not available to me?**

or

**Is pandas just not very 'efficient'? (in the sense that there is a lot of repetition and clutter that makes things hard to read and to understand)**

In the second case: why do so many people prefer python over R?

EDIT: There are so many more confusing examples. I hardly execute a single command that reacts as expected:

```
'EXPERIMENT_NUMBER' in process_events.columns
Out[10]: True
'EXPERIMENT_ID' in process_events.columns
Out[11]: True
process_events.drop(['EXPERIMENT_NUMBER', 'EXPERIMENT_ID'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    raise KeyError("{} not found in axis".format(labels[mask]))
KeyError: "['EXPERIMENT_NUMBER' 'EXPERIMENT_ID'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: "I am still struggling (after a few weeks) with the most simple operations" - I think that's normal. Coming from R background, I find pandas less than intuitive. :shrug: Also, can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: To solve part of the repetition problem, use the `+=` operator

Comment: To be honest, your python code doesn't look to different from the base R solution to your problem. It is just `data.table` which makes it easier.

Comment: Can't you just use the data.table python package?

Comment: @Roland UUh, I did not at all know about this package. I will definitely try it out in my next project! Thx :-)

Comment: Seconding Roland. The datatable package for Python github's can be found [here](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable) with a link to the [documentation](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest). In general R's data handling is simple. Going from R to Python takes some getting used to.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong. 
The datatable package in python doesn't allow to apply functions by group without collapsing the table, like data.table in R: dt[,new_col:=mean(col_1),by=col_2]
 
In python, one can only do: df[:, mean(f.x), by("y")].
Which in R is written: dt[,.(new_col=mean(col_1)),by=col_2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you've written it purposefully verbosely, but it can be written much more simply with a variable and `+=` operator

```
df.loc[(df['PROC_ID'] == proc_id) & (df['SORT_NR'] >= start), 'SORT_NR'] = 
df.loc[(df['PROC_ID'] == proc_id) & (df['SORT_NR'] >= start), 'SORT_NR'] + add
```

becomes:

```
sorted_procs = (df['PROC_ID'] == proc_id) & (df['SORT_NR'] >= start)
df.loc[sorted_procs, 'SORT_NR'] += add
```

I don't know about R, but in Python it's common to structure things this way in complex operations, it's part of [the zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). The way I've written it is more conducive to readability. It's clear what each line does just by glancing at it, and they can be reused later.

Your R example does look more succinct, but Python is much more *general purpose* so oneliners like that don't necessarily fit within the design goals. You're right that there are more characters to represent certain operations, but that is because pandas was designed for python, which is not a "data-first" type language.

So to answer your question, in cases like this, there is more repetition with pandas, and writing with *zen* will make it easier to read.

Comment: Like the term 'data-first', that's exactly expressing what I wanted to say... Wherever you look: people start to use python for exactly that: data manipulation. Is it just me or isn't it confusing that people use a non-data-first language for data-first problems? I keep telling other Data Scientists: 'We are not software developers, we want to answer questions quickly'... but they don't listen to me :-)